# IF condition in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

In a stored procedure I have an IF condition to check whether the `orgID` exists in the result of the query to set the flag. What would be the correct syntax??

```
create procedure temp
(@TEMpID char(6)
)
declare @orgID char(3),flag char(1)
SET flag ='N'

BEGIN
set
 @OrgID =(selecte orgID from table1)
IF @OrgID exists in ( select distinct(OrgID) from table2)
set flag = 'Y'

END

Begin 
select p1, p2, p3, flag
from table3

END
```

Comment: `select orgID from table1` is only going to return a single value? Seems unlikely. Where is the `@TEMpID` parameter used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
IF exists ( select 1 from table2 where OrgID=@OrgID)
   set flag = 'Y'
```

**Note**: I think you have too many `begin/end` blocks.

You can write your proc as:

```
create procedure temp
( 
   @TEMpID char(6)
)
as
BEGIN
   --whole body here
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single select statement

```
SELECT
  p1, 
  p2,
  flag = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT table1.OrgId FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.OrgId=table2.OrgId) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END
FROM table3
```